# Delete ToDo Widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to delete ToDo Widgets in Flutter. I store the Widgets in a list and return that list in the function `_getItems()`.

```
 List<Widget> _getItems() {

final List<Widget> _todoWidgets = <Widget>[];

for (String title in eintrage) {
  _todoWidgets.add(_buildTodoItem(title));
}

return _todoWidgets;
```

}

Here is my function to build a ToDO Widget:

```
Widget _buildTodoItem(String title) {
return ListTile(
    leading: Theme(
      data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white),
      child: Checkbox(
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            isChecked = value!;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
    title: Text(
        title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, color: Colors.white)),
    trailing: FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {

        });
      },
      child: Text(
          'delete', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
    ),
  );
```

}

In the body I use a ListView that creates all the ToDo Items:

```
body: ListView(
    children: _getItems(),
  ),
```

How can I delete one single ToDo Widget when I press the `FlatButton` with the title "delete"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this in FlatButton :

```
onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            eintrage.remove(title);
          });
        },
```